# Mirroring a mesh

Tags: mirror

When I try to mirror my image, it turns out to be the second picture. The first picture is it before it is mirrored. These are steps I did before to get it ready to be mirrored and to mirror it:

**Prep for Mirror:**
Make sure that everything is deselected. If not, press the A key.
Make sure you are in Edit mode.
Left-click the Face Select mode button.
Right-click the face on the flat side of the tail that's highlighted in the video.
Press the X key.
On the Erase menu, click Faces. The faces on that side of the creature's tail should be gone.
If you accidently delete the wrong face, you can always undo by pressing CTRL + Z. You can then go back and redo the steps above.
Press and hold SHIFT and right-click the faces on the flat side of the character's head.
Press the X key.
On the Erase menu, click Faces. The faces on the flat side of the creature's head should be gone.
Press and hold SHIFT and right-click the faces on the flat side of the creature's chest.
Press the X key.
On the Erase menu, click Faces. All the faces that you need to remove should be gone.

**To Mirror:**
Switch from Edit mode to Object mode.
In the Object Modifiers mini-window, left-click Add Modifier and left-click Mirror.
Left-click Merge Limit and type 0.1010. Press ENTER.
CAUTION: Do not click the Apply button yet.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great on why it isn't the same or not proportionate.

Thanks!

Comment: It is all about the origin . . .